# How can I simply determine if there is (not) a result from PDOStatement fetch?

Tags: php, pdo

Consider the following code:

```
$conn = new PDO("connection string", "user name", "password");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `displayname` = :displayname";
$parms = array(':displayname' => 'Test');
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$stmt->execute($parms);

$res = $stmt->fetch();
echo $res == null;
```

and more specifically consider this line: `echo ($res == null);`

If there is no row in the database that matches the `echo` displays a value of `1` -as expected -because the `$res` is in fact `null`. However, if there is a result returned from `$stmt->fetch();` the `echo` **produces nothing.** But, I would have expected it to have produced a `0` because the value of `$res` is an array.

How can I consistently and concisely compare the result to **simply determine if there was a result or not?**

Comment: what happens when you typecast boolean to your $res == null .. cause $stmt->fetch() returns false if not data returned.. so if you get an array may be boolean can give you 1 or true.. not sure though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's no result, it doesn't return `null`. It returns `false` (well, assuming `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` -- to see a full list, [read the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)). Also, `false` casted to a string is an empty string. That's why you're not getting any output.

```
echo false; //Outputs nothing

$s = (string) false;
var_dump($s === ""); //true
```

As for determining whether or not you have a result, you can just do a simple implicit check:

```
$res = $stmt->fetch();
if ($res) { 
    echo 'Got a row!';
} else {
    echo 'No row :(';
}
```

This works because of a few implicit casts. Consider what `fetch` is going to return: either a non-empty array, or `false`. `(bool) $arr === true` only if `count($arr) > 0`. From here, you should be able to see why this works.

(Note: *in theory*, the result set could indeed be an empty row. This would cause `fetch` to return an emtpy array. That would break the implicit comparison as it would then be considered false. I can't imagine this would actually ever happen though. I can't think of a statement that would return a result set with a row that has no columns.)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and exactly what I was looking for -thanks for breaking it down a bit more for me too -I'm new to PHP!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Glad I could help. And you might want to look at the type rules. Some of the PHP casts are rather "wtf?!" inducing at times (like false going to an empty string, but true going to "1").

Comment: Do you mean that if a table has no columns, then `SELECT * FROM tableName` will return empty row?

Comment: @RoyalBg It would depend on the DB, but that is, in theory, one of the possibilities. I cannot imagine what RDBMS would actually allow you to create a column-less table though.

Comment: @Corbin, I have to agree, why in the world wouldn't `false` result in `0`? But hey, when you know the rules it's no big deal, just ***weird!***